# Ecdh key generation in android

Tags: java, android, ecdh

We have an app communicating with ble peripheral for which we have a communication layer ECDH implemented on peripheral so now Android app need to create its own ECDH keypair of 64 bytes length only. How can I create the ECDH key of 64 byes in android

Comment: Do you mean you are using "LE Secure Connections" in the Bluetooth standard when pairing is performed, or do you do some custom crypto in the application?

Comment: @Emil yes after connection is made key exchange should be made before making the actual communication

Comment: I don't understand which of my two options you answer yes to. But if you answered yes to "LE Secure Connections", then everything is built into Android and you don't have to do anything, except call "createBond()" on the BluetoothDevice object.

Comment: @Emil the concept is make a le connection then make ECDH key exchange then transfer the encrypted data using these keys

Comment: Do you want to use the "LE Secure Connections" that is built in to the Bluetooth standard, which internally uses ECDH?

Comment: @Emil we can but hardware is already built we can't change it now we need to do from app only

Comment: So if you want to do it manually, which curve are you using? secp256r1? secp256k1? Something else?

Comment: @Emil secp256k1

Comment: There is no built-in secp256k1 support in Android as far as I know. You can use a standard Java library to get an implementation. Have you checked out Bouncy Castle?

Comment: @Emil bc is now depecrated I think